# How do I figure out where my script is sleeping?

Tags: ruby

One of my unit tests is extremely slow, taking more than a full second for each test. Profiling that test file, the top few lines read:

```
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
198.71    12.28     12.28        2  6140.00  6140.00  Mutex#sleep
 14.40    13.17      0.89     9658     0.09     1.09  REXML::Element#namespace
 10.68    13.83      0.66    18814     0.04     0.08  REXML::Element#root
```

I can't figure out where the sleep call comes from though! My whole application only sleeps in one place, in a class called `Throttle`, and I've inserted a breakpoint in front of it which doesn't trigger during this test. I have tried:

```
class Mutex
  def sleep(time)
    require "byebug"; byebug
  end
end
```

Which never breaks, and I've tried:

```
def setup
  Mutex.define_singleton_method(:sleep) { |time|
    require "byebug"; byebug
  }
end
```

Which also does absolutely nothing. I have also tried both of these with `Kernel` instead of `Mutex`. I have read through my code countless times and I can't for the life of me figure out why my application is constantly sleeping! Can anybody give me any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out `Mutex#sleep` was invoked by `Net::HTTP#post`. My unit test bootstrap script was supposed to override all functions that writes to disk or makes network requests, but I had forgotten to require the functions that I was supposed to override, so the end result was that my overrides were overwritten by the actual functions, causing my unit tests to make real requests to online APIs.

I only discovered this by chance as I was stepping through the code in byebug.

As soon as I fixed the bootstrap script, my unit tests ran as quickly as ever.